# C# crashes when trying to delete non-existent folder

Tags: c#

So basically now I'm struggling to add a if statement to the code... it keeps crashing the application if the directory isn't found. I'd like to add that if the directory isn't found, it'll return a error message into the console which would be `Console.WriteLine("Directory not found.. Aborted.");`

Code that I'm currently using:

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing....");

new System.IO.DirectoryInfo( Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData ) + "/Testing4121" ).Delete( true );

Console.Clear();
```

Comment: DirectoryInfo has an Exists property. Check that first

Comment: Try using a `Try-Catch` instead.  When you check for a folders existence and "then" go to delete it, it might have already been deleted by another process, so you can't rely on an `if {...}` block.

Comment: You should always use `Path.Combine` rather than concatenating path components togeter.

Comment: Use [`File.Delete(path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netcore-3.1). It fails silently if the file doesn't exist (no exception).

Comment: @JohnWu The OP wants to delete an entire folder tree though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Step 1: Maintainability

I'm not a fan of anonymous objects, so let's do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing....");

String appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );
String targetPath  = appDataPath + "/Testing4121";

DirectoryInfo targetDir = new DirectoryInfo( targetPath );
targetDir.Delete( recursive: true );

Console.Clear();
```

### Step 2: Using the correct `System.IO` APIs:

Use `Path.Combine` to concatenate path components, not string concatenation:

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing....");

String appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );
DirectoryInfo targetDir = Path.Combine( appDataPath, "Testing4121" );

targetDir.Delete( recursive: true );

Console.Clear();
```

### Step 3: Checking for existence:

The simplest solution to your problem is to guard `.Delete` with `if( DirectoryInfo.Exists )`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing....");

String appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );
DirectoryInfo targetDir = Path.Combine( appDataPath, "Testing4121" );

if( targetDir.Exists )
{
    targetDir.Delete( recursive: true );
}

Console.Clear();
```

### Step 4: Handling *exceptional* situations:

...that said, other errors can occur when deleting a folder besides directory-does-not-exist, so we should catch those - but **only those** which should be caught (i.e. only catch specific `Exception`-subclasses, only catch `Exception` itself if you know what you're doing - or you're re-throwing it after performing error logging).

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing....");

String appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );
DirectoryInfo targetDir = Path.Combine( appDataPath, "Testing4121" );

if( targetDir.Exists )
{
    try
    {
        targetDir.Delete( recursive: true );
    }
    // See the "Exceptions" list in the documentation for `DirectoryInfo.Delete` to see what to catch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.delete?view=netcore-3.1
    catch( UnauthorizedAccessException uaEx )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Cannot delete directory: a read-only file exists in the directory." );
    }
    catch( DirectoryNotFoundException nxDirEx )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Directory was unexpectedly deleted by another program while I was trying to delete it." );
    }
    catch( IOException ioEx ) // while this includes DirectoryNotFoundException, that's caught above.
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Unexpected IO error: " + ioEx.ToString() );
    }
    catch( SecurityException secEx ) // Don't confuse SecurityException with UnauthorizedAccessException.
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "You do not have permission to delete this directory or a subdirectory thereof." );
    }
    // DO NOT use `catch( Exception ex )` unless the exception is re-thrown using `throw;` to avoid swallowing exceptions that should be caught by a caller higher-up in the call-stack.
    // Only ever use `throw;`, NEVER USE `throw ex;` because that resets the stack-trace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2200?view=vs-2019
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "An unexpected error occurred. Re-throwing." );
        throw;
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "The directory does not exist - no need to delete it." );
}

Console.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put it in a try catch block. Then it automatically ouputs to the console when an error occurs:

```
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Removing....");
            new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/Testing4121").Delete(true);
            Console.Clear();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ e }: Directory not found.. Aborted.");
        }
```

Comment: In .NET, exceptions are expensive and so should only be used for _exceptional circumstances_. Checking if a directory exists isn't really considered "exceptional" - it's better to check `Directory.Exists` and not catch.

Comment: Also, when catching, you should catch the most specific exception type as possible, so your code should catch **only** `DirectoryNotFoundException` but right now your code would catch an `ArgumentException`, `SecurityException`,  `IntegerOverflowException`  and all the others.

Comment: It maybe better to explicitly catch only `DirectoryNotFoundException`s rather than just catching all and possibly output misleading error messages.

Comment: should still do both. The exception is probably exceptional in the first place, and being removed between the check and the delete would be highly exceptional.

Comment: @Dai what code example then would you then recommend?

Comment: @Loominnglynew See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Directory.Exists(path))
{
  // This path is a directory
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
}
```

Comment: Can't really depend on the if() test. Directory could be deleted by another process after the if() but before the delete.

Comment: @Chimera Using a filesystem lock would be excessive in this scenario though (and even filesystem locks aren't 100% guarantees either).

Comment: @Dai That is why the try() block is preferable over the if() test.

Comment: @Chimera I completely disagree.  Dai wrote an answer above which is very well structured.  You should strive to write code that avoids hitting exception blocks, which is why using an if statement to test first is best.  Exception handling is for "exceptions" not routine-processing.  The OP asked for an if statement which is why I took this (reduced from an MSDN example) and provided it, as I'm inferring from their post that it's someone who is just learning.

Comment: I think we can agree that only using the if() test isn't satisfactory.